# Getting a different value than expected runs in a loop. Why?

Tags: c, loops, scanf

So, this program accepts three values, an int, a float and a char while being inside a loop. 
When it asks the user to enter the integer and they write.. let's say, "House" the program falls in an infinite loop.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int i;
    float f;
    char c;

    while(i!=99){

        printf("Enter an int, a float and a char separated by commas: ");
        int count = scanf("%d,%f,%c",&i,&f,&c);
        printf("Int is: %d, Float is: %1.f, Char is: %c",i,f,c);

        if (count != 2){
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nerror\n");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i` is not initialized before using it in loop condition `while(i!=99)`.

Comment: Not only `i` may be used uninitialised, but all variables (except `count`). This because `scanf` may fail for the first call.

Answer (score 1):

In this -

```
if (count != 2){
        fflush(stdin);                  // undefined behaviour
        printf("\nerror\n");
    }
```

Also `count` should be tested against `3` not `2` (`scanf` *will return `3` if successfull* ). Instead of `fflush(stdin)` , use this to clear input stream-

```
int c;
if (count != 3){
   while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!= EOF);
  printf("\nerror\n");
}
```

Also you have `i` uninitialized. So ,either initialize it or instead of using `while` loop use `do-while` -

```
do{
   //your code
  }while(i!=99);
```

Comment: @hydrz I am am not sure which loop are you talking about ?

Comment: Oh, that worked! Yes, I forgot a couple things since I did this code just to ask about it here. Btw, could you explain that line? "while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!= EOF);" I mean.

Comment: @hydrz That inner `while` loop will read from `stdin` and store in `c` until a new line or `EOF` is encountered . In this way `stdin` will be cleared and in next iteration `scanf` will not fail .

Comment: I see... Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

- `scanf()` leave characters which aren't interpreted as data to read, so in next iteration, `scanf()` try to read the characters again and fail again, then it will cause endless loop.
- `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior and do not use it.
- Uninitialized `i` is used in `i!=99`, which is also undefined behavior.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int i=0;
    float f=0.0f;
    char c=' ';

    while(i!=99){

        printf("Enter an int, a float and a char separated by commas: ");
        int count = scanf("%d,%f,%c",&i,&f,&c);
        printf("Int is: %d, Float is: %1.f, Char is: %c",i,f,c);

        if (count != 3){ /* adjusted to match the scanf */
            int dummy;
            while((dummy=getchar())!='\n' && dummy!=EOF); /* skip one line */
            printf("\nerror\n");
            if (dummy == EOF) break; /* there won't be any more input... */
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```